# Open Web Analytics; correct implementation of heatmaps anyone?

Tags: javascript, analytics

the heatmap feature on open web analytics is a really cool one; if you get it to work.
The documentation is incomplete and the wiki is totally unclear. The forum has nothing come up so quite frustrating. Who has implemented heatmaps in OWA and could share how to do it?

So this is the basic example code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var owa_baseUrl = 'http://stats.viewcom.nl/';
var owa_cmds = owa_cmds || [];
owa_cmds.push(['setSiteId', 'xxx']);
owa_cmds.push(['trackPageView']);
owa_cmds.push(['trackClicks']);
owa_cmds.push(['trackDomStream']);

(function() {
    var _owa = document.createElement('script'); _owa.type = 'text/javascript'; _owa.async = true;
    owa_baseUrl = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? window.owa_baseSecUrl || owa_baseUrl.replace(/http:/, 'https:') : owa_baseUrl );
    _owa.src = owa_baseUrl + 'modules/base/js/owa.tracker-combined-min.js';
    var _owa_s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; _owa_s.parentNode.insertBefore(_owa, _owa_s);
}());
//]]>
```

The wiki refers to:

```
http://wiki.openwebanalytics.com/index.php?title=Heatmap
```

adding somehow, somewhere( unclear ):

```
//create the object
var heatmap = new owa.heatmap();
heatmap.generate();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for late answer, but i got here via the Google search myself and was quite disapointed that nobody have answered. I was struggling with the same question - "How to enable/see heatmpas in OWA" until i scanned their demo page from a-z. 
Looks like heat maps are already engaged by default. Just open report for any page and you should see a bottom link in "reports" section. [image: see the screenshot]

Comment: I can see the heatmap option/link but it opens my site's link without port and fails, If I manually insert port in URL that was generated, it redirects to home. Can you guide me on this?

Comment: it's been almost 11 years :D no.